# How to calculate iterative independent event?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Say you iteratively go through an event that has 1/800 success rate and 799/800 failure rate. What's the probability that you draw successfully within the first 100 attempts, or generally x attempts? is it as simple as 1/8?

Furthermore, say you now have a similar independent event but this time it has a 798/800 failure rate, but event A occurs 1/800 and event B occurs 1/800. A or B can only be drawn once, so once drawn it is removed from the table and the other event is now 2/800. What would be the likelihood of hitting both A and B within the first 100 attempts? What would be the likelihood of missing both within 800 attempts?

lastly, what branch of probability would these events come under as I don't know the terminology?

This question is in relation to a game drop table.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. You can do this by editing your question. See also [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What does "iteratively go through an event" mean? Is each of the 100 attempts independent (i.e. draw with replacement), or can "success" only occur once in 800 attempts (draw without replacement)?

Comment: with replacement. Same event iterated until a successful draw.

Comment: It's one minus the probability that you're unsuccessful every time.  Can you see it now?

Comment: Hint for the first question: if $p$ is the chance that event $A$ succeeds, and $q = (1-p)$, then the chance of $n$ consecutive failures, assuming that each *try* is independent of all of the other tries, is $q^n.$  Therefore, the chance of **at least** one success in $n$ tries is $\left(1 - q^n\right).~~$ When using a pocket calculator against such a question, it is often helpful to use logarithms.  For example $n\log(q) = \log(q^n)$.  So you would take $1 - \text{the-antilog-of}\left[n\log(q)\right].$

Comment: Re previous comment, note that computation of the antilog will depend on the base used to compute the logarithm.  For example, if $n\ln(q)$ is calculated where ln refers to the log, base $(e)$, then the antilog would be computed as $e^{n\ln(q)}.$

Comment: To help you with probability terminology, the ***experiment*** is repeated, not the event. An ***event*** is a (measurable) set of possible outcomes. A draw is an experiment. The draw being a success is an event. You could also consider "100 draws with replacement" as a single experiment, and "at least one success" as an event. Each event has a probability (by definition).

Comment: Your second example is incorrectly analyzed.  When A is withdrawn, B has a probability of being drawn of $\frac{1}{799}$, not $\frac{2}{800}$.